# Why am I getting 'Symfony2 No route found for "GET /module/%3C" ...', when similar calls work

Tags: ajax, symfony

I'm getting: this error message:

> No route found for "GET **/*module*/**%3C" (from
>      "http://***site***/app_dev.php/***module***/***page***")

using the following ajax call:

```
   timeStamp = ( new Date() ).getTime();
   $.ajax( {
      method      : 'POST',
      url         : 'http://site/app_dev.php/module/page/Delete/' +
                    timeStamp,
      data        : formData,
      dataType    : 'json',
      async       : true,
      cache       : false,
      contentType : false,
      processData : false,

      success     : function( data ) { ... },

      error       : function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { ... }

    } );
```

Here is the page route annotation and function definitions that I'm trying to call:

```
/**
 * @Route("/module/page")
 * @Route("/module/page/{timeStamp}")
 * @Route("/module/page/Delete/{timeStamp}")
 *
 * @return:    page response HTML string, JSON encoded action results or
 *             JSON encoded error results.
 */
public function pageAction( $timeStamp=NULL ) { ... }
```

What is strange is that this function is successfully used to produce the page that contains several other similar ajax calls that do work in addition to the one above.

Here is one of the calls that work:

```
$.ajax( {
   method      : 'POST',
   data        : formData,
   dataType    : 'json',
   async       : true,
   cache       : false,
   contentType : false,
   enctype     : 'multipart/form-data',
   processData : false,

   success     : function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) { ... ),

   error       : function( data ) { ... }

} );
```

The primary difference is that the ajax call that fails has an explicit url and the one that works uses the implicit address string of the page being displayed.

I tried the call with and without these two parts in the url, but get the same result either way.

I don't know if this is significant, but when I use the debugger in Chrome, the breakpoint at the first code line in the success function briefly highlights and then the page is replaced with the one displaying the 'No route found ...'

Since, the call uses message: 'POST', why would the error say 'Get' and using the explicit url that includes '/Delete' and '/' + timeStamp, why aren't these shown in the error message?

Incidentally. In the ajax call with the explicit url, I'm adding a timeStamp to prevent a previously cached response from being returned rather than making the actual call to the server to delete the information referenced in the formData object.

In another ajax call that returns the information that is supposed to be deleted by the failing call, I found that even though 'cache: false' was set, the call would return an outdated response from the a previous call if I didn't include the timeStamp in the explicit url, but with the timeStamp included, that case works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the html element, an anchor tag, that called the function containing the ajax I thought wasn't working, also had an 'href' that maked it's own request to the server for a page that didn't exist, and which contained the strange '%3C' characters.

So the real answer is the don't get wrapped around the axle and be sure to check out everything leading up to the apparent problem.

The give-away in this case was that the call leading to the error message was occurring slightly before the ajax server-side call to the right function, which is why the debugger was showing that even though the execution stopped at the right breakpoint in the success function control was 'yanked' away as the Not found error displayed.